# How to use arrays that are in side a list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, search, data-structures

I have a number of arrays that I added them to a list and then I want to pass this arrays one by one. But I do not know how to do this. the following is my code.

```
String [] anArray = new String[10];
String [] anArray2 = new String[10];
String [] anArray3 = new String[10];
List<String[]> kList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
kList.add(anArray);
kList.add(anArray2);
kList.add(anArray2);
```

How to access this list and use each array in it alone?

Comment: `String[] element = kList.get(0)` (for index `0`). Some remarks: - you should wirte the brackets directly after the type, no blank: `String [] anArray` -> `String[] anArray` --- You could use a `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. Mixing Arrays an generics is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: `kList.get(0)`?

Comment: Why are you doing this? It smells like you really should be using something else, like a `List<SomeClass>`.

Comment: Somewhat like chrylis, I'd like to know the goal.  Making complicated structures like this is probably better served by making a dedicated class that has the exact semantics you want.  It keeps the complicated access/update logic on one place and the method names can be meaningful, allowing a "literate" programming style.

Comment: You can create a two dimensional array to  access in a situation like this.

Comment: @Turing85 Using spaces is a matter of taste as Java syntax rules are quite flexible with regard to white space. Some us have learned that more spaces make the code much more readable. We need not be constrained by the conventions of yesteryear when screens were smaller, code was often printed on paper, and so on.

Comment: @BasilBourque I completely agree, this is why I advice to never neglect optional parentheses around `if`, `else`,... . Readability is a main concern wrt. code style and `String[]` is (at least in my opinion) much more readable when you spell `[]` always as "array". This communicates without a doubt that the type of a variable is a `String`-array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate over the `List` using a foreach loop if you wish to process each array independently.

```
String [] anArray = new String[10];
String [] anArray2 = new String[10];
String [] anArray3 = new String[10];
List<String[]> kList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
kList.add(anArray);
kList.add(anArray2);
kList.add(anArray2);

for (String[] arr : kList) {
    // Perform actions or pass the `arr` value
    // This will go through each array in kList and store the array
    // in arr so you can process each array independently
}
```